# How to handle POST requests to a deep links in my app (made by other apps)?

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, appauth, apple-id

I am trying to implement 'Sign in with Apple ID' in my Android app and I can't figure out how to make my app a target for POST request to my deep links (using https: scheme).

I already use deep links in my app for both navigation and authentication with Facebook, however when Apple making a POST request to my deep link URL my app is not invoked, but rather it makes request to an actual web-site using web-view. I have searched for proper intent action to configure this in my AndroidManifest.xml file, but no matter what I try it doesn't seems to work.